# How can I hide the API connection in a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a code which I know how to perform certain API call with a link, it looks like this

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="https://testapi.internet.bs/Domain/Transfer/Initiate?ApiKey='.$user.'&Password='.$pass.'&Domain='.$domain.$ext.'" role="button">Restart Transfer</a>
```

This works, but on the page of course it will show ApiKey=(actualKey) and the User and the PASSWORD which is not what I want. I understand this is how it works in a Link, but How can I do this with a button instead.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" name="restartTransfer">Restart Transfer</button>
</form>
```

and Im guessing PHP action such as (Not saying this is the way, any way is appreciated using php, jquery or javascript)

```
if(isset($_POST['restartTransfer'])) {

}
```

Right now I do have it done like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button[name = 'restartTransfer']").click(function(){
        window.location = "https://testapi.internet.bs/Domain/Transfer/Initiate?ApiKey=<?php print $user;?>&Password=<?php print $pass;?>&Domain=<?php print $domain;?>";

});
});
```

But this doesn't hide it, this just launches web browser window showing the API key user and pass..

How can I hide the API information in a button push (in the same page if possible)

The idea would be

1. Click this button
2. It loads the API call url (not shown)
3. Returns with a message "Complete" in a Div container called #message for sake of example

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might hide the actual URL from user in browser address bar. It will not, however, protect the credentials from being viewed either through profiling network requests, or viewing the source of the web page. I suggest using a PHP proxy to make it more secure.

```
$("button[name='restartTransfer']").click(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://testapi.internet.bs/Domain/Transfer/Initiate?ApiKey=<?php print $user;?>&Password=<?php print $pass;?>&Domain=<?php print $domain;?>",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text/plain',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#message').text(data); // print results
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log('Error', xhr);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Since this script is run within WHMCS environment and is only meant for our staff, the high security isn't an issue. What I just don't want is for the page to load into a white api call page spitting out bunch of useless information for my staff. I just want the call to be performed on button push, returning a customized sentence "Complete" when the loading of the page in the background is done :).. So this code will load the page without leaving the page :)

Comment: @SteiniPetur, use `$('#message').text('Complete')` in the code I provided.

Comment: Note if api on different domain it needs to be CORS enabled

Comment: I have hit a snag

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://testapi.internet.bs/Domain/Transfer/Initiate?ApiKey=testapi&Password=testpass&Domain=testdomain.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://removed' is therefore not allowed access.

Now I need to talk to IBS and ask them how im suppose to be able to use their API without leaving the page, Maybe this will work when I have moved it over from the testAPI to the actual IP which I enable our actual domain to interact with.. I will let you know if this is the answer Im looking for

Comment: I can only imagine that if CORS is enabled or I somehow can get them to allow our domain to access like this, judging by the console error, it tells me that If it was enabled my script would have run pushing the button and returned with the message. I see no reason not to accept this response :)

Comment: I ended up having to do it a slightly differently but your answer did get me there, 

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "restartTransfer.php",
        data: {

I had to pass the variables over to the PHP script which executed cURL since direct ajax call was a no go... still this answer is accepted, it got me almost all the way..

Answer (score 0):

Using curl you can do it secure with php

```
<?php
```

class EBCommon{
    public function call($sessionId, $sessionInfo, $realUser, $url, $parameters)
    {
        $apiUrl = "http://mycompany.edubrite.com/oltpublish/site/";
        $curl_request = curl_init();

```
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl . $url);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);

    if($sessionId != null){
        $cookieStr = "SESSION_ID=" . $sessionId;
        if($sessionInfo != null){
            $cookieStr .= "; SESSION_INFO=" . $sessionInfo;
        }
        //print($cookieStr . "\n");
        curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookieStr);

        if($realUser != null){
            $headerStr = array("REAL_UNAME: ".$realUser);
            curl_setopt($curl_request, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headerStr);
        }
    }

    $response = curl_exec($curl_request);
    //print($response);
    $error = curl_error($curl_request);
    $result = array(
                     'body' => '',
                     'error' => '',
                     'http_code' => '',
                     'session_info' => '',
                     'session_id' => ''
                     );
    if ( $error != "" )
    {
        $result['error'] = $error;
        return $result;
    }

    $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl_request,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $result['body'] = substr( $response, $header_size );
    $result['http_code'] = curl_getinfo($curl_request,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl_request);   

    preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie:\s{0,}(?P<name>[^=]*)=(?P<value>[^;]*).*?$/im', $header, $cookies, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($cookies as $match) {
        if($match["name"] == "SESSION_ID"){
            $result['session_id'] = $match["value"];
        }
        if($match["name"] == "SESSION_INFO"){
            $result['session_info'] = $match["value"];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

}
?>